# Start last 3 images from new line - css solution needed

Tags: html, css, image, newline

There is a set of images (more than 3):

```
<img src="http://path.to/my/img1.jpg">
<img src="http://path.to/my/img2.jpg">
<img src="http://path.to/my/img323.jpg">
<img src="http://path.to/my/img99.jpg">
<img src="http://path.to/my/img2.jpg">
<img src="http://path.to/my/img323.jpg">
<img src="http://path.to/my/img99.jpg">
```

If you don't apply any styles, they go in a row (if space allows to). That's fine, however I want the last 3 images always appear on the next line. Is it possible to make it using pure css?
I've found a close solution:

```
img:nth-last-child(3){display:block;}
```

However, it breaks the images in three lines (that makes sense as it is `display:block` for third image from the end).

[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/9ajey/)

**Looking for a pure css solution.**

Thank you.

Comment: are your images always the same and do they have fixed widths?

Comment: @Haradzieniec:check my answer and demo..!! you just need css alone..!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

use

`clear:both` in css for last three images

```
img {
    float:left;
}
img:nth-last-child(3) {
    clear:both;
}
```

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/997E5/)